# Equality of regular language

Tags: regular-expressions

I am showing that two regular expressions are equal. In one of intermediate steps, I thought of the equaility: $$(RS+R)^* = (RS)^*R(RS)^*R(RS)^*....R(RS)^* = R^*(RS)R^*(RS)...R^*$$

Is it true? I mean, can I use it in my proof steps?

Comment: It’s certainly true that $(RS+R)^*=((RS)^*R)^*(RS)^*=(R^*RS)^*R^*$; whether you can use it without proof depends on your instructor and on what’s already been proved.

Comment: Anything with ... is not a good regular language definition, so it is hard to prove that the two are equal regular languages.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there any better equality for $(S+T)^*$ ?

Comment: $(S^*T)^*S^*$ and $(T^*S)^*T^*$ and the analogues with the extra factor on the left are certainly the simplest that occur to me at the moment.